# Thesis name (singular vs. plural)

Tags: grammatical-number

I need to choose a name for my masters thesis (computer science degree). My current name proposal is following:

> Computer Vision Application in a Driver Assistance System

What I am not sure of is whether parts of name should be in singular or plural. I consider also following:

> Computer Vision Application in Driver Assistance System**s**
>
> Computer Vision Application**s** in Driver Assistance System**s**

And less so this:

> Computer Vision Application**s** in a Driver Assistance System

The plan is to design a single "assistance system" (probably Froward Collision Warning) but the name may allow some maneuvering space in case more will be done (a more complex system than only FCW or even multiple systems - although multiple is rather unlikely). The means will be mainly stereo vision (but could be more again, I am not sure now).

May I ask for a hint on my naming issue? Are there any "naming conventions" for grammatical numbers? I am also not sure about the preposition ("in") - would a "for" be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the stakes here are not grammatical, but to do with your perceived "*humility*". The convention in scientific academic writing is always to let others decide to what extent your results can be generalized. If you've been dealing with just one application and one DAS, then restrict yourself to talking about your own experience and keep everything in the singular. As for whether or not to use the indefinite article *a*, the *initial* article can be omitted (like in a newspaper headline) for reasons of concision, but I would retain "*a* Driver Assistance System", because with *two* missing articles the title of the thesis starts to look too much like ungrammatical English.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I forgot that "a" in "Computer Vision Applications in Driver Assistance System" - it was not an intention to leave it out - thanks for spotting that too though! I made a correction.

Comment: What is your opinion on the in/for prepositions?

Comment: You could use either. If the application is designed for use in a DAS and could not conceivably be used in any other context, then go with *for*.

Comment: Regarding the "Application" - do you think that is appropriate? Or would you suggest anything better?

Comment: To give you my considered answer I'd need to read the thesis. I'm sure it's an absolute belter, but .. not today! *Application* seems fine to me. However, if whatever it is incorporates both software and hardware elements, you might prefer a more general term such as *component*.

Comment: I have to choose the name but the thesis does not exist itself yet. It will deal primarily with a software solution so "application" will be fine probably.